# What might I be doing wrong to get "Error: s > 0 is not TRUE" for a nlmer model?

Tags: r

I am attempting to learn lme4, and I'll admit up front that my statistical academic training was in traditional ANOVA designs at the home of SAS (NC State) over 20 years ago.  I now have about 4-5 years of experience with R, but mostly with traditional general linear models with all factors treated as fixed effects.

I now would like to estimate the parameters for a von Bertalanffy growth model for an experiment with fresh-water mussels.  Shell length was measured once per year for 4 years on known individuals (ID), so this is a repeated measures design.  Ultimately I would like to add a main treatment factor and a split-plot factor.  But, at the moment I can't get the simplified model to run.  The R code that I'm using is:

```
VBGF <- function(Linf, k, age, age.0) {
  Linf * (1-exp(-k*((age-age.0))))
}
VBGF <- deriv(L ~ VBGF, namevec=c("Lin", "k", "age.0"), function.arg=VBGF)
mod1 <- nlmer(L ~ VBGF(Linf,k,AGE,age.0) ~ (Linf+k+age.0|ID), 
              mussels,
              start=c(50,0.1,-11),
              verbose=TRUE)
```

I get the following error, and I have been completely unsuccessful in finding a reference to what it means.

```
Error: s > 0 is not TRUE
```

It's probably something simple that I'm overlooking, so I apologize for my ignorance in advance.

Comment: The call to `deriv` looks very strange, I am pretty sure you are misusing that function.

Answer (score 2):

The line that causes the error in the function `nlmer` is

```
stopifnot(length(start$fixef) > 0, s > 0, inherits(data, 
    "data.frame"), nrow(data) > 1)
```

By looking at the code, I get the impression that `s` is the number of names in the list `start`. In your case, you provided a `vector` without names, which probably causes the error.

The help pages says

```
start: a named list of starting values for the parameters in the
      model. (..)
```

So they are quite specific about the fact that it must have names. In the examples you will see that they also give names to the parameters.

```
## nonlinear mixed models
(nm1 <- nlmer(circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ Asym|Tree,
             Orange, start = c(Asym = 200, xmid = 725, scal = 350)))
```